Combine metric and retrieve metric values as property?
Lets say we have two metrics with sample data points as below
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", resource="cpu", pod:"pod1"...} 0.5
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", resource="cpu", pod:"pod2"...} 1
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", resource="memory", pod:"pod1"...} 17898878
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", resource="memory", pod:"pod2"...} 67656776

node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", pod:"pod1"...} 0.3
node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", pod:"pod2"...} 0.2

Now below are the requirements

I want to filter only "cpu" data points from  kube_pod_container_resource_requests
Sum all data points based on namespace and managed_cluster for both metrics
combine both data points based on namespace and managed_cluster

Finally I want result data like below.
{managed_cluster:"id1", namespace:"ns1", cpu_request: 1.5, cpu_usage: 0.5}

Can you help me to write PROMQL query for this scenario. I am not sure how to combine metric and get the values into property like cpu_request/cpu_usage.

Maybe this is possible, but I'd argue you shouldn't do it. Query requests and usage separately and join them on client side. Can you explain how you intend to use results of desired query?
